# Full width submenu in Bootstrap 3 without using MegaMenu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple top-fixed nav using Bootstrap 3.0 which utilizes the submenu feature.  I'm attempting to have my submenu take up the full width of the container, not just the width of the combined submenu elements.  The problem appears to be coming from the `ul.dropdown-menu` code in which the width is set to ~160px;  Not only that, but it refuses to extend left, past the dropdown menu tab.  This is a problem because my collapse-nav is set to sit on the right side.  Oy.

Below is a fiddle of my current solution.

[FIDDLE FIDDLE, YA'LL](http://jsfiddle.net/wVrE9/)

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown active">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Films <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="container">
              <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="placeholder" id="pause"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="placeholder" id="hiccup"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="placeholder"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="placeholder"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="placeholder"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="placeholder"><a href="#"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (sorry it's so specific, I'm using SASS):

```
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color: #454545;
  border: none; 
  }
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top .container .navbar-collapse.collapse.pull-right ul.nav.navbar-nav li.active a, .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top .container .navbar-collapse.collapse.pull-right ul.nav.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #ffcc00;
  background-color: #454545;
  height: inherit; 
  }
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top .container .navbar-collapse.collapse.pull-right ul.nav.navbar-nav li.dropdown.active.open ul.dropdown-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white; 
  }
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top .container .navbar-collapse.collapse.pull-right ul.nav.navbar-nav li.dropdown.active.open ul.dropdown-menu .container {
  background-color: white; 
  }
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top .container .navbar-collapse.collapse.pull-right ul.nav.navbar-nav li.dropdown.active.open ul.dropdown-menu .container ul.list-inline {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%; 
  }
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top .container .navbar-collapse.collapse.pull-right ul.nav.navbar-nav li.dropdown.active.open ul.dropdown-menu .container ul.list-inline li.placeholder {
  margin: 0 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #999999; 
  }
```

So far the closest solution I've come across is adding a container within the dropdown menu, however I'm still unable to extend the dropdown menu beyond it's ~160px width.

The general goal is to have a full-width dropdown menu.  Currently not worried about what it looks like on mobile devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I use Yamm3 to do this, it's quite easy to integrate and allows you to specify a full width for your mega menu.

http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/